# immutable js flat zip two lists

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

If I have two immutable lists,

```
const a = [1,2,3];
const b = [a,b,c,d];
```

is there an easy way to merge/zip them to result in:

```
const c = [1,a,2,b,3,c,d];
```

Comment: Do you need pure js solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is interleave what you are looking for: https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/interleave

```
const a = List([1, 2, 3]);
const b = List([a, b, c, d]);
a.interleave(b)
```

Comment: This is incorrect, as the docs you linked to mention, "The shortest Collection stops interleave." meaning your code above will produce `[1,'a',2,'b',3,'c']` and the `d` will be dropped.

Answer (score 0):

`const a = [1, 2, 3]` don't make this array immutable at all. What `const` does is to guarantee that you're not reassigning `a`. Pushing or removing items to `a` don't constitute a reassignment.

This is a real immutable list using `immutable.js`:

```
const a = List([1, 2, 3]);
```

Now.. back to zip.

If you don't want another reference, you can just use a `for` in the smallest list and build the zip yourself. If you want a ready-made function, you might consider using [Underscore's Zip](http://underscorejs.org/#zip), which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to develop a function from scratch then you can use the code below. Basically, the function merges the two array as interleaving the two. Consider 2 arrays, array1 = [1,2,3,4] and array2 = [a,b,c,d,e,f]. Then the below code will output a new array [1,a,2,b,3,c,4,d,e,f]

```
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var k = 0;
var len1 = array1.length;
var len2 = array2.length;
var flag = true;

var newArr = [];

//Merge the 2 arrays till the smaller sized array

while (i < len1 && j < len2)
{
  if(flag){
   newArr[k] = array1[i];
   i++; k++;
   flag = false;
  }

else{
  newArr[k] = array2[j];
  j++; k++;
  flag = true;
 }
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of array1[], if there are any */

while (i < len1)
{
    newArr[k] = array1[i];
    i++;
    k++;
}

/* Copy the remaining elements of array2[], if there are any */

while (j < len2)
{
   newArr[k] = array2[j];
   j++;
   k++;
}

console.log(newArr)
```